# Cookie not set after HTTP request with Set-Cookie response header

Tags: laravel, cookies, axios, nuxt.js

Context: I'm trying to couple a separate frontend (Nuxt.js) with a Laravel backend. Session (logged in user etc.) is maintained by the backend and should be stored and updated in the frontend using cookies. I am making API calls using Axios.

I am currently running my frontend on localhost:3000 and my backend on 127.0.0.1:8000. When I make API calls from the frontend, I get the following headers in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 15 Oct 2017 13:05:24 GMT
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=fuqQf1fX3ZwQYl7xORGPopgZhD4qw5Mfi8lFrHTJ; expires=Sun, 15-Oct-2017 15:05:24 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/;
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.10
```

From what I understand, the browser should now set/update the `laravel_session` cookie. However, when I check the cookies in Chrome devtools, nothing changes.

Are the different URLs (or at least ports) an issue here? Am I missing some kind of header or directive that is required? I've done some research but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: how did you use cookie in laravel. did you triedthis approach with another browser?